# How to do a multidimensional array in python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I need to do a data structure in python just like this:

```
array(
      1 => array(url => "http://wwww.ff.com", msg => "msg 1..."),
      2 => array(url => "http://wwww.yy.com", msg => "msg 2..."),
      3 => array(url => "http://wwww.xx.com", msg => "msg 3..."),   
      );
```

I have search the documentation, but no clue. Can someone give me clue on how to do this?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use a list of dictionaries:

```
a = [{"url": "http://wwww.ff.com", "msg": "msg 1..."},
     {"url": "http://wwww.yy.com", "msg": "msg 2..."},
     {"url": "http://wwww.xx.com", "msg": "msg 3..."}]
print a[0]["url"]
# http://wwww.ff.com
```

Alternatively, you could use a list of tuples

```
a = [("http://wwww.ff.com", "msg 1..."),
     ("http://wwww.yy.com", "msg 2..."),
     ("http://wwww.xx.com", "msg 3...")]
print a[0][0]
# http://wwww.ff.com
```

or a list of named tuples:

```
from collections import namedtuple
UrlTuple = namedtuple("UrlTuple", "url msg")
a = [UrlTuple(url="http://wwww.ff.com", msg="msg 1..."),
     UrlTuple(url="http://wwww.xx.com", msg="msg 2..."),
     UrlTuple(url="http://wwww.yy.com", msg="msg 3...")]
print a[0].url
# http://wwww.ff.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Data types in Python can be freely nested:

```
multi = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

If you need a more indepth solution, NumPy has a powerful selection of [array handling tools](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for dictionaries:

```
[{"url":"http...", "msg":"msg 1..."}, {"url":"http...", "msg":"msg 12..."}, ...]
```